# How get by git diff only binary files?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, git-diff

Now I'm using `git diff --numstat` to get a list of modified files. Those, that start with `-      -` are binary files. For example:

```
$ git diff --numstat first_commit_hash second_commit_hash
```

[image]

But how do I get a list of only binary files? Is there any filter for binary files?

Comment: Try `git diff --numstat first_commit_hash second_commit_hash | grep -e "^-\s-"`

Comment: Oh, thanks. It work great. Where I can read more about matching pattern in git?

Comment: @llya Google `grep` and `regular expression`. They are a bit complicated to learn all but it can help even if you get to know only a few rules. Some git commands, `git log` for example, have grep-ish options like `--grep` to help filter the output. Besides, we can always use `grep` to filter. About GNU grep, http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how I can get only the part of a line without matching pattern? I need for name of binary files only.